# Load in different html content at every track/chapter HTML5 video

Tags: html5-video

I want to create cuepoints/chapters on a HTML5 video, and then at every one load in some html content like links for example below the video. Is this possible? If so how? I've googled but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 video objects have a property called `currentTime`. It contains the number of seconds in that the user is in the video. The great thing about it is it updates even when the user uses the seek bar. [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Seeking_through_media)

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wykCe/3/) for you. It uses a four-second video that I "borrowed" from that MDN page. All the HTML that displays for the video is contained in a handy object that you can modify easily.